# Change the color, marker size and name of single value - Plotly scatter

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-express

I have a dataframe and I am using Plotly to draw a scatter plot. I want to change the color, size and name of just a single value there, e.g. datapoint "one". I am not sure how to do this. I have been trying `for_each_trace` aiming to change the marker shape but never works.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame(index=['one','two','three','four'],data=[[3,4],[2,5],[2,3],[6,4]],columns=['a','b'])
fig1=px.scatter(df1, x="a", y="b",text=df1.index.astype(str))
fig1.update_traces(textposition='top center')

fig1.for_each_trace(
    lambda trace: trace.update(marker_symbol="square") if trace.name == 'one' else ())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `px` doesn't create one trace per index, but one trace per unique value found in the data assigned to `color` (ie. if `color` is unset, all markers belong to the same trace) :

> [`color`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter.html) (str or int or Series or array-like) – Either a name of a column
> in data_frame, or a pandas Series or array_like object. Values from
> this column or array_like are used to assign color to marks.

You can add a column in the dataframe to distinguish highlighted point(s) from others and use this column as `color` when calling `px.scatter` :

```py
df1['c'] = ['highlighted' if one else 'normal' for one in df1.index == 'one']
# or just 
# df1['c'] = df1.index == 'one' # the above is just to get meaningful `trace.name`

fig1 = px.scatter(df1, x="a", y="b", color="c", text=df1.index.astype(str))
fig1.update_traces(textposition='top center')

fig1.for_each_trace(lambda trace: trace.update(marker_symbol="square") if trace.name == 'highlighted' else ())
```

You can also [control the color order](https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#controlling-discrete-color-order) via `color_discrete_sequence` or `color_discrete_map`.